# No audio in Agora video call

Tags: audio-streaming, agora.io

I have a call setup, but in my projects I sometimes have one of these three situations:

- No audio from remote users
- Remote users can't hear me
- Sometimes both.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is finding the source of the issue.

To do so, head first to [Agora Video Call](https://videocall.agora.io/), and check if audio is working fine there.

### If audio is not working

With the computer that's not sending audio:

1. Ensure that the audio input device is properly connected, and that the affected user has selected a suitable device when there are multiple device options.
2. In system settings, open the audio input device (or recording device) window. Ensure that the system uses a correct device and that the device is not muted.
3. Speak into the audio input device, and check whether the volume bar of the audio input device changes according to the volume.

   - If the volume bar changes, the audio input device is working. Proceed to step 3 to check the audio output device.
   - If the volume bar does not change, the audio input device is not working. Try restarting the device. If this does not help, try using another audio input device.

If it's still no good…

Check the audio output device:

- Ensure that the audio output device is properly connected, and that the affected user has selected a suitable device when there are multiple device options.
- In system settings, open the audio output device (or playback device) window. Ensure that the system uses a correct device and that the device is not muted.
- Play an audio file, and check whether the user can hear sound. If not, the audio output device is not working. Try restarting the device. If this does not help, try using another audio output device.

If the above are still not working, then it could be an issue with your computer's sound card. There are several ways to check this depending on your machine. Try searching "resent sound card on ".

### If the audio is working

1. Ensure that all users can access the correct audio devices.
2. Check whether each user joins the channel successfully through the onJoinChannelSuccess/didJoinChannel callback.
3. Check whether the audio is muted by the adjustRecordingSignalVolume(0), adjustPlaybackSignalVolume(0), or mute-related methods.
4. If a user uses headphones, check whether you call setEnableSpeakerphone(false) to route the audio to the headphones.

### Contact Agora customer support

If the issue persists, contact Agora customer support and [submit a ticket](https://agora-ticket.agora.io/) with the following information:

The name of the channel where the users cannot hear sound.
The user IDs of the users who cannot hear sound in the channel.
The time frame during which the users cannot hear sound.
You can also use [Agora Analytics](https://dashboard.agora.io/analytics/call/search) in Console to gain a broad view of call issues for every user. See [Agora Analytics Overview](https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Analytics/aa_guide?platform=All%20Platforms) for details.